# BizTalk connectivity with CRM using SSO Account

Tags: biztalk, dynamics-crm-online, biztalk-2013

We are using a custom WCF Behaviour in BizTalk server 2013 R2 to connect Dynamics CRM online.

This custom Behaviour connects to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/RST2.srf` and send a SOAP requests to get a token back and then appends the token to the actual CRM request to connect CRM Organization service.

When we are using onmicrosoft account, login.microsoftonline is returning a valid token but throwing error "Direct login to WLID is not allowed for this federated namespace;" when trying to connect with a SSO account

Comment: Is your custom behaviour fetching the credentials to use from SSO, or are you trying to use the SSO Affiliate setting in the Adapter?